# File type "Required" doesnt work with iPhone?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a web-based application that uploads photos to the server through the mobile devices. I added a "required" attribute so as to restrict the page to go to next page without selecting an image. It works completely fine with Android and Microsoft OS but when i try to use it with iPhone, it goes to the next page. Here is code below.

HTML

```
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" action="login.php" method="POST">
  <input name="image" type='file' required id="image" onchange="readURL(this);" accept="image/*" capture="camera" /><br/><br/>
  <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" /><br/><br/>


  <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
    </form>
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_FILES['image']))
{
 session_start();
      $_SESSION['str'];
      $_SESSION['img'];
      //$uploaded = $_SESSION['str'];
      $image = basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $_SESSION['str'].$_SESSION['img']);
echo "upload successful";
}
```

when using in Android and Microsoft OS it prompts to choose the file but in iOS it gives the message upload successful. How to fix it.

Comment: It seems iOS / Safari don't support that completely yet: http://caniuse.com/#search=required

Answer (score 0):

In iOS Safari `required` attribute partial support. Refers to lack of notice when form with required fields is attempted to be submitted. Try to add in PHP `if` statement to check whether a file is transferred, and if not block access to the next page.

Comment: For Example? I mean what shall i check?? its extension or size or what??

Comment: @Vishu check is a successful upload - `if ($_FILES['image']['error'] == 0) {...}`. If I helped you please press the response is useful and accepted.

Comment: it works fine.. But the problem is when i try to login from a different page it shows the message Upload Successful in the page.

Comment: Can i use such code

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $_SESSION['str'].$_SESSION['img'])){
echo "Upload Successful"; 
}

Comment: Yes _move_uploaded_file_ return _true_ if successfull. But I think this code would be better: `if($_FILES['image']['error'] == 0 && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $_SESSION['str'].$_SESSION['img'])){ echo "Upload Successful"; }`. So we'll check on the success and the upload process and the process of moving file.